# How to update a property of a JSON object using NewtonSoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{
    "code": "GENDER",
    "value": { "option": "ML" }
}
```

I would like to update the `option` property to `"Male"` if the value is `"ML"` and `"Female"` if the value is `"FM"`.

I have got to this point, but am unsure how to proceed:

```
JArray contentobject = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contentJSON);  
JObject voicgObj = contentobject.Children().FirstOrDefault(ce =>   ce["code"].ToString() == "GENDER") as JObject;
JProperty voicgProp = voicgObj.Property("value");
```

I don't know how to get to the `option` which is a child of `value`.

Thanks in advance. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can access the object by using properties as keys:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string gender = (string)obj["value"]["option"];
```

For your example, try:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var val = obj["value"];
string option = (string)val["option"];

if (option == "ML")
   val["option"] = "Male";

if (option == "FM")
   val["option"] = "Female";

string result = obj.ToString();
```

Comment: How can i update the values for Serial_no and Serial_code if my JSON has   "parameters": [
    {
      "key": "serial_no",
      "value": "213223324"
    },
    {
      "key": "serial_code",
      "value": "1102"
    }
  ]

Comment: obj.parameters.find(p => p.key=="serial_no").value = 123;

Answer (score 1):

Another way, with minimal property retrieving:

```
var val = voicgObj["value"] as JObject;
JProperty optionProp = val.Property("option");
string option = optionProp.Value.Value<string>();

if (option == "ML")
    optionProp.Value = "Male";
else if (option == "FM")
    optionProp.Value = "Female";
```