# Updating ICollection

Tags: c#, icollection

I have this code inside my **HTTP PUT Method**;

```
var toUpdate = context.MyTableData.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == someId);
id = data.id,
name = data.name,
age = data.age,
JObject otherData = (JObject)data;
JToken value; 
if(otherData.TryGetValue("children", out value)){
   var someIds = (JArray)value;
   foreach (var someId in someIds){
       toUpdate.MyChildrenTable.Add(new MyChildrenTable{ //-- This line right here
       id = data.id,
       name = data.name,
       age = data.age,
   }
   }
}
```

Based on the code, I only wanted to update to update my data. However, using **Add**, this gives me another set of data (which is, obviously not updating the data). How I may able to modify my code? I tried using **Attach** but no good. Is there any way like *Attach* or something to have my code corrected?

To avoid confusions, all of the code are working. I only wanted to modify it in order to have it's flow **Update** my data instead of **Adding** another set of data. `MyTableData` is updating, but the `MyChildrenTable` is not, since it's on **Add** method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853066/how-to-update-a-property-of-a-json-object-using-newtonsoft

Comment: Generally, for updating children of an entity, I use GraphDiff: https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff

Comment: Those links were great. Perhaps, there'll be another way to solve it. Thank you guys