# Unable to Write json variable c# getting an error

Tags: c#, json, oop, c#-4.0

I get an error when I try to serialize or update a json file. I just want to update the value of **"balance"** inside a json file and I got the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64774144/update-property-in-json-file-with-c-sharp)... I can't seem to make it work for my project. The Users.json file does not change whenever I check it.

here is my code:

> Users.json

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "sachin",
    "password": "sachin1",
    "firstName": "Sachin",
    "lastName": "Karnik",
    "birthdate": "2011-6-14",
    "balance": 20000,
    "cardNumber": 12345
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "dina",
    "password": "dina1",
    "firstName": "Dina",
    "lastName": "Meyers",
    "birthdate": "2012-8-20",
    "balance": 20000,
    "cardNumber": 23456
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "username": "andy",
    "password": "andy1",
    "firstName": "Andy",
    "lastName": "Rose",
    "birthdate": "2010-2-11",
    "balance": 20000,
    "cardNumber": 34567
  }
]
```

> Menu.cs

```c#
public static void BankMenu(object? balance, object? user)
  {
  
   User[]? Users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(Login.jsonResponse);
   int bal = Convert.ToInt32(balance);
   int money;
   
 try{
   money = ValidateAmountInput(bal, user);
       if (money <= bal && money != 0)
       {
        bal -= money;
        foreach (var usr in Users!)
        {
         if (usr.FirstName == user?.ToString())
         {
          usr.Balance = bal;

         }
        }
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Users, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(Login.jsonResponse, json);
  }
   }
   catch(System.Exception e)
   {
      WriteLine(e);
   }
```

> My Error
> [image]

Comment: " an error when I try to serialize or update a json file" serialize or update? I never heard about a serialize error. Can you post an error message pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have a bug

```
  File.WriteAllText(Login.jsonResponse, json);
```

instead of ogin.jsonResponse you have to use a file path

```
File.WriteAllText(<full file path\Users.json>, json);
```

Comment: I think his file path is stored in Login.jsonResponse, which would obviously fail to deserialize `User[]? Users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(Login.jsonResponse)`

Comment: @ScottyD0nt Then it would be a newtonsoft.json DeserializeObject error, but it is a save file error.

Comment: yeah, I didn't see the exception that got added to the post. looks like you got it right.